# RestSharp .NET Core com Certificado SSL

Tags: c#, .net-core, ssl, restsharp

Preciso conectar a uma API que exige certificado digital. Estou utilizando o RestSharp no meu projeto, e encontrei o seguinte código de como fazer isso:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(... certificado...);
```

Porém, o RestClient do .NET Core não possui a propriedade ClientCertificates. Como posso resolver isso? Obrigado;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente, o RestSharp teve grandes alterações. Varias configurações foram movidas para a classe RestClientOptions.

Você provavelmente precisa de um código com a seguinte semântica:

```
var certificates = new X509CertificateCollection()
certificates.Add(... certificado ...)
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.myorg.com") {
    ThrowOnAnyError = true,
    Timeout = 1000,
    ClientCertificates = certificates
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Comment: funcionou aqui, muito obrigado

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :)